# Rails Rest Service GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, activerecord

I have set up a Rails REST Service and I am having a problem showing a single record.  Here is the URL that I am trying to hit:

```
http://website:3000/users/2/timesheets/21
```

Controller code:

```
  def show
    puts "SHOW"
    puts params.inspect
    @timesheets = User.find(params[:user_id]).timesheets(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @timesheets }
    end
  end
```

I know the params are getting to the controller, but it is not using the `:timesheet_id`.  Here is the console output to show what I mean:

```
Started GET "/users/2/timesheets/21" for **.**.***.** at 2013-03-19 06:12:11 -0400
Processing by TimesheetsController#show as */*
  Parameters: {"user_id"=>"2", "id"=>"21"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "2"]]
  Timesheet Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "timesheets".* FROM "timesheets" WHERE "timesheets"."user_id" = 2
Completed 200 OK in 120ms (Views: 36.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)
```

I see the timesheet id of 21 in the parameters hash.  A query is then made to get the user, but then all of the timesheets for that user are grabbed.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
@timesheet = @user.timesheets.find(params[:id])
```

This should run a query as follows:

```
SELECT "timesheets".* FROM "timesheets" WHERE "timesheets"."id" = 21 AND ("timesheets"."user_id" = 2) LIMIT 1
```

The corresponding view should be referring to `@timesheet` variable and not `@timesheets`.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I could of done it all in one line: `User.find(params[:user_id]).timesheets.find(params[:id])`.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

What Prakash suggests works, but executes two queries: one to get the user and one the get the timesheet. There does not seem to be any reason to do `User.find(...)` first. Might as well query the timesheets table only, which will only execute one query and is thus faster:

```
@timesheet = Timesheet.where('user_id = ? and id = ?', params[:user_id], params[:id]).first
```